# https warning on asp.net postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

I have a simple webpage that has cascaded dropdowns (not Ajax). The code works fine when I use the regular http: url however when I install this on a secured server at https: I get a warning on postback from the dropdown. The warning says "*Security Warning - Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely*"?

How do I "deliver" all the content securely?

Answer (score 4):

When serving an HTML document over HTTPS, you should make sure all the linked content (scripts, css documents, images, etc) are also referenced using HTTPS. Using HTTP will work, but results in the warning you're asking about.

There are a number of tools that can help you find resources referenced using HTTP instead of HTTPS, including, but not limited to:

- The "network" tab in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- The "Network" page in Chrome's developer tools (CTRL+SHIFT+I)

Answer (score 2):

This message means that some content was delivered via the standard http protocol. You should check to see if you have any content which is being referenced with a full url > I.E. http://example.com/myphoto.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your referenced files (images, css and javascript) are loading from https:// and not http://

If check the Net tab in Firebug you can see a list of everything that your page is loading.